# How to use Google Cloud Firestore on Ionic without AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know if there is any way to implement firestore in Ionic without using angularfire, that is, since the google documentation about firebase and firestore is easier for me.
First I install the libraries

```
npm install --save firebase-admin@^5.4.0
```

then import them into app.module

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
```

but when I try to initialize

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    clientEmail: "foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

a lot of errors appear, I really dont know the right way to initialize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in the [documentation for the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) says (emphasis mine):

> The Admin SDK lets you interact with Firebase from **privileged environments**...

This means you should **not** be using the Firebase Admin SDK in the front-end of your Angular (or other) application. Using the Admin SDK in the front-end would allow all your users to for example: create endless user accounts or delete them, wipe your entire database, send FCM notifications to all users of your app, etc.

Instead [install the regular Firebase SDK for JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). From that documentation:

> The Firebase SDK is also available on npm. If you don't already have a `package.json` file, create one via `npm init`. Next, install the `firebase` npm package and save it to your `package.json`:
>
> ```
> $ npm install firebase --save
> ```
>
> To use the module in your application, require it from any JavaScript file:
>
> ```
> var firebase = require("firebase");
> ```
>
> If you are using ES2015, you can import the module instead:
>
> ```
> import * as firebase from "firebase";
> ```
>
> Then, initialize the Firebase SDK using the code snippet from above, which should look like this:
>
> ```
> // Initialize Firebase
> // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
> var config = {
>   apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
>   authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
>   databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
>   storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
> };
> firebase.initializeApp(config);
> ```

If you still have errors after this, open a new question with the code of what you tried and the error message that you get.

Comment: Thank you so much for let me notice that... i really felt a little confused about this, and i wasnt knowing that firestore is part of firebase library in js... Thank you so much, it is so usefull for me!